# Objective C to Swift JSON Parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift

how can i convert this code into Swift?

```
- (void)fetchFeed
{
    NSString *requestString = @"https://bookapi.bignerdranch.com/private/courses.json";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
        [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                        completionHandler:
         ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

             NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                        options:0
                                                                          error:nil];
             self.courses = jsonObject[@"courses"];

             NSLog(@"%@", self.courses);

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self.tableView reloadData];
             });
         }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

i try to convert it in this, but xcode crashes

```
 func fetchFeed(){

        var requestString = "http://bookapi.bignerdranch.com/courses.json"
        var url = NSURL(string: requestString)
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        var dataTask:NSURLSessionDataTask = self._session.dataTaskWithRequest(req, completionHandler: { (data : NSData!, response : NSURLResponse!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

           //var json:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data: NSData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: NSError!)

            var json: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: NSErrorPointer.null()) as NSDictionary

            self._courses = json["courses"]![0] as NSArray

            println("\(json)")
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

the problem should be this line  `self._courses = json["courses"]![0] as NSArray`
i guess it has to be some sort of errors with optionals. dunno what exactely

How can i solved it? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the difference between your Objective-C and Swift code for that line:

```
// objc
self.courses = jsonObject[@"courses"];

// swift
self._courses = json["courses"]![0] as NSArray
```

You're trying to grab the first element of the array in Swift instead of the array itself. Change to this to match your prior code:

```
self._courses = json["courses"]! as NSArray
```

Comment: Also be sure it's an array and not a dictionary.